# trigger mysql to sql server with sys_exec

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

i use this script in mysql triger after insert on tbl_produk

```
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE cmd CHAR(255);
DECLARE result INT(100);
SET cmd=CONCAT('/usr/bin/php ', 'http://localhost/triger/add_post.php?produk=', NEW.produk, '&jumlah=', NEW.jumlah);
SET result = sys_exec(cmd);
END;
```

reference from https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39598/update-sql-server-from-mysql

but not runing,
i hope an solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If columns should be numeric than to convert varchar.

```
SET cmd=CONCAT('/usr/bin/php ', 'http://localhost/triger/add_post.php?produk=',convert(varchar(50),NEW.produk), '&jumlah=', convert(varchar(50),NEW.jumlah));
```

Comment: thanks this work for insert into tbl_produk, but not update to tbl_trigger_produk,

Comment: @RikyCloud Not say thanks but given right marks and vot

Comment: i get error in sqlyog when add code "convert" 
like this
Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(50),NEW.produk), '&jumlah=', CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),NEW.jumlah)); SET resu' at line 8

Comment: i think this problem is sys_exec function not exist, how to add lib_mysqludf_sys in mysql? 3hour i search this problem but not runing :D, can you help plis